# How do I prevent Rplots.pdf from being generated?

Tags: r, cairo

I am working with some R code that generates a number of images as png files; however, a `Rplots.pdf` file keeps on being generated in the working directory, is there  a way to prevent this from happening?

```
library(Cairo)
CairoPNG(file = "graphs.png")
nf <- layout(matrix(c(1:8), 2, 4, byrow=T), c(1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1), TRUE)
for (k in 1:num.k) {
    plotMatrix(connect.matrix.ordered[k,,], log = F, main = paste("k=", k.vector[k]), sub = paste("Cophenetic coef.=", rho[k]), ylab = "samples", xlab ="samples")
}
y.range <- c(1 - 2*(1 - min(rho)), 1)
plot(k.vector, rho, main ="Cophenetic Coefficient", xlim=c(k.init, k.final), ylim=y.range, xlab = "k", ylab="Cophenetic correlation", type = "n")
lines(k.vector, rho, type = "l", col = "black")
points(k.vector, rho, pch=22, type = "p", cex = 1.25, bg = "black", col = "black")
dev.off()
```

Comment: Did you mean `Rplots.png`?? I can't see how @Andrie's answer would stop a PDF device being created, but can see it being a solution if you actually mean `Rplots.png`???

Comment: @Gavin Simpson - Close, now there is a `Rplot001.png` file that is being generated and not cleaned.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem (in part because your example isn't self-contained).  Does something simpler like the following also produce the rogue file?  `library(Cairo);
CairoPNG(file = "graphs.png");
layout(matrix(c(1:4), 2));
for (k in 1:4) plot(1,k);
dev.off()`

Comment: @Aaron - Not sure myself yet either. The code is largely undocumented and there is a lot of it related to plotting charts that we don't even need any more. I might have to update the question again once I clean some more code out.

Comment: Sounds like a strong possibility then that there's some code that opens a device without first opening a file, as in my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wonder if you have another command that opens a device before or after the code snippet you've given us.  When you're all done run `dev.cur()` to see if there was a device left open.  If not, it should return the null device.

Here are ways you can recreate getting a `Rplots.pdf` or a `Rplot001.png`; the `layout` and `par` commands open a device if one isn't open, and since no filename has been given, it uses the default filename.

```
options(device="pdf")
layout(1:4)
dev.off()

options(device="png")
par()
dev.off()
```

Maybe seeing that happen here will give you a clue as to what's happening with your code.

Comment: This ended up being the problem - a plot being generated without a file being opened up for it. Very obscure location in the code though.

Answer (score 38):

I know this is a very old post and surely the OP has solved this. But I encountered this similar situation while working with plotly. Converting a ggplot output into a plotly output generated the similar error of not being able to open file 'Rplots.pdf'.

I solved it by simply including :

```
pdf(NULL)
```

I'm not sure of the reason for the error, have not been able to figure that out, but this small line helped removing the error and displaying my plots as I would expect in plotly and ggplot combinations.

Comment: Great tip, @Syamanthaka. This had bugged me for a long time. But I found that while `pdf(NULL)` suppresses Rplots.pdf from being created when R is run in batch mode, but also suppresses the Plots window display in RStudio, if `pdf(NULL)` is run before  any plot is displayed there. You can avoid the RStudio problem by using `if(!interactive()) pdf(NULL)` near the top of a program that you may run in batch or interactively.

Comment: Per [base::options documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/options.html), it looks like the environment variables R_INTERACTIVE_DEVICE and R_DEFAULT_DEVICE might also be used to address this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the source code for `CairoPNG`:

```
function (filename = "Rplot%03d.png", width = 480, height = 480, 
    pointsize = 12, bg = "white", res = NA, ...) 
{
    Cairo(width, height, type = "png", file = filename, pointsize = pointsize, 
        bg = bg, ...)
}
```

This tells you that `CairoPNG` takes `filename=...` as a parameter, and passes this to `Cairo` as the `file` parameter.

I can see how this can lead to confusion, but the point is that your call to `CairoPNG` should be:

```
CairoPNG(filename="graphs.png")
```

See if that works...

Comment: That goes a long way to solving the problem, but it looks like `options(device = "png")` is also needed to get things running correctly.

Comment: Did some more checking and the when the `options(device = "png")` is on a `Rplot001.png` file is generated, likewise, if it is off the `Rplots.pdf` is generated. Any ideas what might be going on? The `Rplot001.png` file does have valid data in it from an aggregate report.

Comment: Sorry, no.  I've never used `Cairo`. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently after upgrading to R-3.0.3 (yes we're a little behind!).  It turns out that **palette("default")** opens a device now, though it didn't used to.