# Why RStudio two plots give only one page filesystem pdf output?

Tags: r, debian, rstudio

Code where I have to explicitly decleare `pdf` to get even one page output into filesystem with RStudio, but failing to get two pages on the filesystem target

```
library("ggplot2")
library("datasets")

options(device="pdf") # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535927/how-do-i-prevent-rplots-pdf-from-being-generated
filename.pdf <- paste0(getwd(), "/", "Rplots", ".pdf", sep = "")
pdf(file=filename.pdf)

data(iris)
plot(iris)

dat.m <- data("mtcars")
print(head(dat.m)) 

ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=hp, colour=factor(cyl))) + geom_line() # https://stackoverflow.com/a/38278702/54964
# TODO Output nothing so wrong!

print(getwd())
print(warnings())
dev.off() # nenecssary with RStudio
```

Output in RStudio: one page
Output in Rscript: two pages
Expected output: two pages

Prompt output in all where no errors

```
[1] "/home/masi/Workspace"
Warning message:
In sink() : no sink to remove
```

OS: Debian 9
RStudio: 1.0.143
R: 3.4.0

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but you need to use `print(ggplot(...` if in a script

Comment: @user20650 You are right! Please, add it as an aswer because it is rigbt so I will not forget this anymore again. - - Is there any way to avoid many `print` commands there, like printing all figures lastly only once?

Comment: maybe relevant as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675066/ggplots-qplot-does-not-execute-on-sourcing